# Database design issue regarding identifying relationships and many to many relationships

Tags: mysql, database, many-to-many, identifying-relationship

I have a weird database design issue that I'm not sure if I'm doing this right or not. Since my current design is really complicated, I've simplified it in the following diagram with a comparison using houses and occupants (not my actual entities).

So, here is what part of the database design looks like:

[image]

Standard Conditions:

- Multiple houses
- Multiple floors per house
- Multiple bedrooms per floor

Not-so-standard Conditions:

- Each occupant can live in multiple houses
- Each occupant can have multiple bedrooms per house
- **Each occupant can only have one bedroom per floor, per house (this is the tricky part) For example, they can have one bedroom on floor 1, one bedroom on floor 2 and one bedroom on floor 3, but never two bedrooms on the same floor**

Thus, what I'm trying to accomplish is this. In the app design, I know the `house`, I know the `floor` and I know the `occupant`. What I need to find out with this information without the user specifying is what `bedroom` the `occupant` has based on those 3 criteria. There are two solutions. The first is that in the `occupants_has_bedrooms` table, I make the primary key the `occupants_id`, `bedrooms_floors_id` and the `bedrooms_floors_houses_id`. However, when I take away `bedrooms_id` from the primary key, the table is no longer an identifying relationship to the parent (`bedrooms`). It is an identifying relationship though because it couldn't exist without the parent. Therefore, something tells me I need to keep all four ids as the primary key. My second option is a unique index between those three values, however this is when I considered I may be approaching this wrong.

How do I accomplishing this?

Comment: There are many ways to solve this problem, and the ideal one will depend on how the database is used.  Is bedroom ownership going to be updated regularly?  Or will it be relatively static?  Can you provide any other sort of usage data?

Comment: Yes, bedroom ownership is managed by an administrator and can be updated whenever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a general database design strategy that is not specific to MySQL but should still be helpful.

It's good that you know how you are going to query your data, but don't let that overly affect your model (at least at first).

The first thing to be clear on is what is the PK for each table?  It looks you are using composite keys for `floors` and `bedrooms`.  If you used an informationless key (ID column per table) strategy for all tables except your intersection table `Occupants_has_bedrooms`, it would makes your joins simpler.  I'm going to assume you can, so here's how to go from there:

The first thing I would change is to get rid of floors_house_id column in bedrooms - this is now redundant and can be gotten from a join.

Next, make the following changes to `occupants_has_bedrooms`:

1. The PK for should only be two columns, occupants_id and bedroom_id.  (why? Because a primary key should only contain enough info to uniquely identify a row).
2. Remove the `bedrooms_floors_houses_id`, as that's determined by `bedrooms_floors_id` and is not needed.
3. add a unique constraint on (`occupants_id`, `bedrooms_floors_id`) to enforce your "not so standard" conditions.

Finally, do an inner join with all tables except `Occupants`, add your three conditions in the WHERE clause.  This should get you the result you want. If you really want the composite keys, you can still do it cut it gets messy.  Sorry I'm not near an editor or I'd diagram it for you.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I'v drawn the diagram that you described here: http://i.imgur.com/Odi0j.png is this correct? If so, the database doesn't have any constrains on allowing the same occupant to have multiple bedrooms per floor, unless I'm getting confused, I don't believe this solution fixes the problem.

Comment: Ok, if you want to enforce the constraint in the database then your second idea - using a unique constraint - seems like the best idea because it clearly models your intent.  I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would design the database reverse of what u did.

```
House
  id
  name
  Floors -- Many to many

Floor
  id
  name
  Bedrooms -- Many to many
  optional: you can have a back pointer to house

Bedroom:
  id
  name
  Occupants -- many to many
  optional : back pointer to floor

Occupant:
  id
  name
  optional : back pointer to Bedroom
```

Now having this many to many table you can query your conditions rather easily.